# My saga function is not being called at all when calling my action?

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-saga, dispatch

I joined a big/medium project, I am having a hard time creating my first redux-saga-action things, it is going to be a lot of code since they are creating a lot of files to make things readable.

So I call my action in my componentDidMount, the action is being called because I have the alert :

```
export const fetchDataRequest = () => {
  alert("actions data");
  return ({
    type: FETCH_DATA_REQUEST
  })
};

export const fetchDataSuccess = data => ({
  type: FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS,
  payload: {
    data,
  },
});
```

This is my history saga : ( when I call the action with this type, The function get executed )

```
export default function* dataSaga() {
    // their takeEverymethods  
    yield takeEvery(FETCH_DATA_REQUEST, fetchData);
}
```

This is what has to be called : ( I am trying to fill my state with data in a json file : mock )

```
export default function* fetchTronconsOfCircuit() {

    try {

        // Cal to api
        const client = yield call(RedClient);
        const data = yield call(client.fetchSomething);

        // mock 
        const history = data === "" ? "" : fakeDataFromMock;
        console.log("history : ");
        console.log(history);

        if (isNilOrEmpty(history)) return null;

        yield put(fetchDataSuccess({ data: history }));
    } catch (e) {
        yield put(addErr(e));
    }
}
```

And this is my root root saga :

```
export default function* sagas() {

  // many other spawn(somethingSaga);
  yield spawn(historySaga);

}
```

and here is the reducer :

```
const fetchDataSuccess = curry(({ data }, state) => ({
  ...state,
  myData: data,
}));

const HistoryReducer = createSwitchReducer(initialState, [
  [FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS, fetchDataSuccess],
]);
```

The method createSwitchReducer is a method created by the team to create easily a reducer instead of creating a switch and passing the action.type in params etc, their method is working fine, and I did exactly what they do for others.

Am I missing something ?

I feel like I did everything right but the saga is not called, which means it is trivial problem, the connection between action and saga is a common problem I just could not figure where is my problem.

I do not see the console.log message in the console, I added an alert before the try-catch but got nothing too, but alert inside action is being called.

Any help would be really really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
yield takeEvery(FETCH_DATA_REQUEST, fetchData);
```

should be

```
yield takeEvery(FETCH_DATA_REQUEST, fetchTronconsOfCircuit);
```